# How can I include FreeTextTable() with the Rank column in a complex query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, full-text-search

I have a case where I am querying records with up to 20 `Where()` clauses (each is conditionally added) plus the following:

```
IQueryable<Event> query;
query = dbContext.Events.FromSqlRaw("SELECT e.* FROM Events e INNER JOIN FreeTextTable(Events, *, {0}) as t on e.Id = t.[KEY]", queryText);
if (location != null)
    query = query.WhereWithinRange(location, maxDistance ?? 0);
// lots more if ...
var listEvents = await query.ToListAsync();
```

The problem is, that does not return the `Rank` psuedo-column. So I then have to, after running the above query, make this additional query to tie the Rank to the returned listEvents.

```
var listRanks = await dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<FullTextTable>(
    $"select * from FreeTextTable(Events, *, {queryText})")
    .ToListAsync();
```

I then iterate through `listRanks` and assign any matching element to the record in `listEvents`. The `Event` model has a `[NotMapped]` property I use for this.

Is there a way to get the `Rank` in the initial query so I don't have to run this query twice? ANd if not, if what I am doing is the best I can get, should I get the list of `Event.Id` values from 'listEvent' and pass those in the second query so it only considers the records who's `Id` is in the passed in list?

In case needed, this is not a model in the DbContext:

```
public class FullTextTable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This corresponds to the primary key of the row in the table where the match is found.
    /// </summary>
    public int Key { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This indicates the relevance of the search result. A higher RANK value indicates a more
    /// relevant result.<br/>
    /// These will generally be in the range of 0 to 1000, but can be higher.
    /// </summary>
    public int Rank { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(Key)}: {Key}, {nameof(Rank)}: {Rank}";
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that you can add the columns to your SELECT? `SELECT ...,, t.Rank... from `

Comment: @siggemannen That doesn't help by itself for EF Core mapping, you need to actually have a C# type that you are selecting in the LINQ query.

Comment: You can expand ``Events`` with Rank and do as @siggemannen say above? ``not return`` ->``not take``?

Answer (score 1):

In EF Core 8 you can use an unmapped type directly.

```
var query =
    from e in dbContext.Events
    join t in dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<FullTextTable>("SELECT t.* FROM FreeTextTable(Events, *, {0}) as t", queryText)
        on e.Id = t.Key
    select new Some {
        e,
        t.Rank
    };
```

You would either need to move your `WhereWithinRange` functions to before that join, or modify them to take an actual (not anonymous) combined type containing the Rank.

In older versions of EF Core, you need to map a Keyless Entity in your `OnModelCreating`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FullTextTable>().HasNoKey();
```

And use `context.Set<>` instead.

```cs
join t in dbContext.Set<FullTextTable>().FromSql(.....
```